# creating script weblogic windows service

Tags: java, windows-services, weblogic12c

I created a script to automatically start my weblogic once my computer boots. The script I have is:

```
echo off
SETLOCAL

set DOMAIN_NAME=new_domain 
set USERDOMAIN_HOME=C:\Users\erick\Desktop\Materials\apps\weblogic_12c\user_projects\domains\new_domain
set SERVER_NAME=myserver 

set WLS_USER=xxxxx
set WLS_PW=xxxxxx

call "C:\Users\erick\Desktop\Materials\apps\weblogic_12c\wlserver\server\bin\installSvc.cmd"
pause
ENDLOCAL
```

This script is created under domains\new_domain\config folder.

My installSvc.cmd looks like this: (I didn't make any change. So it is as the weblogic installer created it)

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL


set WL_HOME=%MW_HOME%\wlserver
call "%WL_HOME%\common\bin\commEnv.cmd"

@rem Check that the WebLogic classes are where we expect them to be
:checkWLS
if exist "%WL_HOME%\server\lib\weblogic.jar" goto checkJava
echo The WebLogic Server wasn't found in directory %WL_HOME%\server.
echo Please edit your script so that the WL_HOME variable points 
echo to the WebLogic installation directory.
goto finish

@rem Check that java is where we expect it to be
:checkJava
if exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" goto runWebLogic
echo The JDK wasn't found in directory %JAVA_HOME%.
echo Please edit your script so that the JAVA_HOME variable 
echo points to the location of your JDK.
goto finish

:runWebLogic

@rem the service loads dll file, so the JAVA_VM *must* be correct
if exist %JRE_HOME%\bin\client (
set JAVA_VM=-client
) else if exist %JRE_HOME%\bin\server (
set JAVA_VM=-server
) else if exist %JRE_HOME%\bin\jrockit (
set JAVA_VM=-jrockit
)



:noResetJavaVM
if not "%MEM_ARGS%" == "" goto noResetMemArgs
set MEM_ARGS=-Xms32m -Xmx200m

:noResetMemArgs

@echo on

set CLASSPATH=%WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH%;%CLASSPATH%

@echo ***************************************************
@echo *  To start WebLogic Server, use the password     *
@echo *  assigned to the system user.  The system       *
@echo *  username and password must also be used to     *
@echo *  access the WebLogic Server console from a web  *
@echo *  browser.                                       *
@echo ***************************************************

rem *** Set Command Line for service to execute within created JVM

@echo off

if "%ADMIN_URL%" == "" goto runAdmin
@echo on
set CMDLINE="%JAVA_VM% %MEM_ARGS% %JAVA_OPTIONS% -classpath \"%CLASSPATH%\" -Dweblogic.Name=%SERVER_NAME% -Dweblogic.management.username=%WLS_USER% -Dweblogic.management.server=\"%ADMIN_URL%\" -Dweblogic.ProductionModeEnabled=%PRODUCTION_MODE% -Djava.security.policy=\"%WL_HOME%\server\lib\weblogic.policy\" weblogic.Server"
goto finish

:runAdmin
@echo on
set CMDLINE="%JAVA_VM% %MEM_ARGS% %JAVA_OPTIONS% -classpath \"%CLASSPATH%\" -Dweblogic.Name=%SERVER_NAME% -Dweblogic.management.username=%WLS_USER% -Dweblogic.ProductionModeEnabled=%PRODUCTION_MODE% -Djava.security.policy=\"%WL_HOME%\server\lib\weblogic.policy\" weblogic.Server"

:finish
rem *** Set up extrapath for win32 and win64 platform separately
set WLSVC_EXE_TO_USE=wlsvcx64
if "%WL_USE_X86DLL%" == "true" (
 set EXTRAPATH=%WL_HOME%\server\native\win\32;%WL_HOME%\server\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%WL_HOME%\server\native\win\32\oci920_8
 set WLSVC_EXE_TO_USE=wlsvc
)

if "%WL_USE_IA64DLL%" == "true" (
 set EXTRAPATH=%WL_HOME%\server\native\win\64\;%WL_HOME%\server\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%WL_HOME%\server\native\win\64\oci920_8
 set WLSVC_EXE_TO_USE=wlsvc64
)

if "%WL_USE_AMD64DLL%" == "true" (
 set EXTRAPATH=%WL_HOME%\server\native\win\x64\;%WL_HOME%\server\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%WL_HOME%\server\native\win\x64\oci920_8
 set WLSVC_EXE_TO_USE=wlsvcx64
)

rem *** Install the service
"%WL_HOME%\server\bin\%WLSVC_EXE_TO_USE%" -install -svcname:"wlsvc %DOMAIN_NAME%_%SERVER_NAME%" -javahome:"%JAVA_HOME%" -execdir:"%USERDOMAIN_HOME%" -maxconnectretries:"%MAX_CONNECT_RETRIES%" -host:"%HOST%" -port:"%PORT%" -extrapath:"%EXTRAPATH%" -password:"%WLS_PW%" -cmdline:%CMDLINE%

ENDLOCAL
```

When I execute my first script, it creates a windows service. For some reason, it creates it as **wlsvc new_domain_myserver** So it has a space in the name. When I try starting the service, it gives me an error saying it can't start it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Near the last line it is explicitly calling:

```
rem *** Install the service
"%WL_HOME%\server\bin\%WLSVC_EXE_TO_USE%" -install -svcname:"wlsvc %DOMAIN_NAME%_%SERVER_NAME%" -javahome:"%JAVA_HOME%" -execdir:"%USERDOMAIN_HOME%" -maxconnectretries:"%MAX_CONNECT_RETRIES%" -host:"%HOST%" -port:"%PORT%" -extrapath:"%EXTRAPATH%" -password:"%WLS_PW%" -cmdline:%CMDLINE%
```

Your problem is unrelated to the name. There is no problem with spaces in the service name. Open `Services` from your Start menu... most of them have names with spaces.

The error saying the service can't start is likely related to your to your `CMDLINE`. Can you post the full output of the command? Does it attempt to start weblogic at all? If not (there are no log files), it's definitely a bad command line.

Run the `.cmd` file manually. Add `-debug` on the last line before `-install` to get more output.

Comment: So the isntallSvc scripts I didnt write it. That script is what weblogic generated when I installed it. I haven't change it. I am not sure what you mean by CMDLINE not been quoted

Comment: Understood (I checked my own `installSvc.cmd` and compared to yours. It looked similar. There must be something higher up in how it builds the command, an env variable, etc that is causing a problem)

Comment: Could you check the first script and compare it with yours?

Comment: Your question is a little confusing, why would you want to run the install service command every time the computer boots? Installing it once should be sufficient. The service would call the startWebLogic script. Wouldn't you want to run `startWebLogic.cmd` instead?

Comment: My ultimate goal is for weblogic to start automatically once my computer (server) starts. That is what I need and I am having issues with that